# I want to deploy a monorepo application with 2 microservices inside on heroku but only one starts

Tags: heroku, nestjs, monorepo

```
Project
|    .git
|
|____Microservice 1 (name:login)
|    |  Procfile
|
|____Microservice 2 (name:negocios)
|    |  Profile
| 
| 
| package.json (global)
```

package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "api",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "",
  "author": "",
  "private": true,
  "license": "UNLICENSED",
  "scripts": {
    "postinstall": "tsc --sourceMap false",
    "build": "nest build",
    "format": "prettier --write \"apps/**/*.ts\" \"libs/**/*.ts\"",
    "start": "node dist/apps/login/main.js && node dist/apps/login/main.js",
    "start:dev": "nest start --watch",
    "start:debug": "nest start --debug --watch",
    "start:prod": "node dist/apps/api/main",
    "lint": "eslint \"{src,apps,libs,test}/**/*.ts\" --fix",
    "test": "jest",
    "test:watch": "jest --watch",
    "test:cov": "jest --coverage",
    "test:debug": "node --inspect-brk -r tsconfig-paths/register -r ts-node/register node_modules/.bin/jest --runInBand",
    "test:e2e": "jest --config ./apps/api/test/jest-e2e.json"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@nestjs/common": "^9.0.0",
    "@nestjs/config": "^2.3.4",
    "@nestjs/core": "^9.0.0",
    "@nestjs/jwt": "^9.0.0",
    "@nestjs/mapped-types": "*",
    "@nestjs/microservices": "^9.4.3",
    "@nestjs/mongoose": "^9.2.2",
    "@nestjs/passport": "^10.0.0",
    "@nestjs/platform-express": "^9.0.0",
    "argon2": "^0.30.3",
    "class-transformer": "^0.5.1",
    "class-validator": "^0.14.0",
    "mongoose": "^7.3.0",
    "passport": "^0.6.0",
    "passport-jwt": "^4.0.0",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.13",
    "rxjs": "^7.2.0",
    "ts-node": "^10.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@nestjs/cli": "^9.0.0",
    "@nestjs/schematics": "^9.0.0",
    "@nestjs/testing": "^9.0.0",
    "@types/express": "^4.17.13",
    "@types/jest": "29.2.4",
    "@types/node": "18.11.18",
    "jest": "29.3.1",
    "source-map-support": "^0.5.20",
    "ts-jest": "29.0.3",
    "ts-loader": "^9.2.3",
    "tsconfig-paths": "4.1.1",
    "typescript": "^4.7.4"
  },
  "jest": {
    "moduleFileExtensions": [
      "js",
      "json",
      "ts"
    ],
    "rootDir": ".",
    "testRegex": ".*\\.spec\\.ts$",
    "transform": {
      "^.+\\.(t|j)s$": "ts-jest"
    },
    "collectCoverageFrom": [
      "**/*.(t|j)s"
    ],
    "coverageDirectory": "./coverage",
    "testEnvironment": "node",
    "roots": [
      "<rootDir>/apps/"
    ]
  }
}
```

in file package.json I have modified the script as follows but it didn't work: "start": "node dist/apps/login/main.js && node dist/apps/login/main.js",

because only microservice 1 called "login" starts, and I need both microservice 1 and then microservice 2 to start

microservice 1 runs on port 3001 like a traditional nest application and microservice 2 communicates over the tcp protocol